# Azure Service Bus topic with exclusive, autodelete subscriptions with a generated name

Tags: publish-subscribe, azure-servicebus-topics

How can I create topic and subscribe on it multiple independent subscribers with different subscriptions for each without specifying subscription names. If the subscriber disconnect, the corresponding subscription should be automatic removed. This case can be realised with rabbitmq server for logging purposes, for example. https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html.

> In the .NET client, when we supply no parameters to queueDeclare() we create a non-durable, exclusive, autodelete queue with a generated name.

If it is impossible, how can I wrap .net client for realising this case? Thanks.

Comment: ``If the subscriber disconnect, the corresponding subscription should be automatic removed.`` Can you explain more about your actual requirement? Does "the subscriber disconnect" mean a subscriber (client user) disconnect or the app stop?

Comment: Both cases I think. For each subscribing I have only one client. A client can disconnect manualy, stoped or crushed. In all cases I want the corresponding subscribing to be deleted automaticaly. Possibly In a link above it is explaned more clearly. A possible solution: to generate unique GUID as subscribing name for each new client. if the client stops manually, I remove the subscription manualy, if it is crushed, I use SubscriptionDescription.AutoDeleteOnIdle Property for automatic removing.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned in your comment, you can create new subscription with unique GUID as subscription name when the client connect (or app start). And specifying [SubscriptionDescription.AutoDeleteOnIdle property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptiondescription.autodeleteonidle?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_SubscriptionDescription_AutoDeleteOnIdle) to set the TimeSpan idle interval after which the subscription is automatically deleted.

```
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

var subscriptionname = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

if (!namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(topicname, subscriptionname))
{
    SqlFilter updatedMessagesFilter =
        new SqlFilter("mypro = 'test'");

    namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(new SubscriptionDescription(topicname, subscriptionname) { AutoDeleteOnIdle = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) },
        updatedMessagesFilter);
}
```

When client disconnect, you can delete the subscription manually.

```
if (namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(topicname, subscriptionname))
{
    namespaceManager.DeleteSubscription(topicname, subscriptionname);
}
```

**Note**: to guarantee 100% delete subscription, you can retain information about client and subscriptionname (unique GUID) in an external storage, and every time when a client connect/reconnect, you can detect if a record exists in external storage that indicates a subscription (used by this client before) is still not be deleted for current client, if the record exists, you can delete that subscription before you create a new subscription.